# How do I load parameter values used on last build in Jenkins and edit them if needed?

Tags: jenkins

I'm using the latest release of Jenkins, and I would like to see all the parameters of my previous build in the latest build and would like to change any of them if needed. The parameters in my Jenkins job include:

- File parameter
- Text parameter
- Drop down boxes
- etc.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The [Rebuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Rebuild+Plugin) allows to rebuild a parametrized build without entering the parameters again. It also allows to edit the parameters before rebuilding.